# Add total of 3 rows for specific id

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

Students

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
studentId        first        last        gender        weight
-------------------------------------------------------------
1                John         Doe         m             185
2                John         Doe2        m             130   
3                John         Doe3        m             250
```

Lifts

```
-------------------
liftId        name        
-------------------
1             Bench Press
2             Power Clean  
3             Parallel Squat
4             Deadlift
5             Shoulder Press
```

StudentLifts

```
------------------------------------------------
studentLiftId   studentId     liftId     weight 
------------------------------------------------
1                1            1          185
2                2            3          130   
3                3            1          190
4                1            2          120
5                2            1          155   
6                3            2          145
7                1            1          135
8                1            1          205   
9                2            3          200
10               1            3          150
11               2            2          110
12               3            3          250
```

I would like to have four top lists:

1. Bench Press
2. Parallel Squat
3. Power Clean
4. Total of the above 3

I can successfully grab a top list for each specific lift using the following query:

```
SELECT s.studentId, s.first, s.last, s.gender, s.weight, l.name, sl.weight 
FROM Students s 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM StudentLifts 
  ORDER BY weight DESC
  ) sl ON sl.studentId = s.studentId 
  LEFT JOIN Lifts l ON l.liftId = sl.liftId 
  WHERE l.name = 'Bench Press' 
  AND s.gender = 'm' 
  AND s.weight > 170 
  GROUP BY s.studentId 
  ORDER BY sl.weight DESC
```

However, I am stuck on how to add the highest total of each lift for each student.  How can I first find the highest total for each student in each lift, and then add them up to get a total of all three lifts?

**Edit**

The result set that I am looking for would be something like:

```
-------------------------------------------------
studentId    first    last    weight
-------------------------------------------------
3            John     Doe3    585
1            John     Doe     475
2            John     Doe2    465
```

I also forgot to mention that I would actually like two lists, one for students above 170 and one for students below 170.

Comment: Can you show us what the desired result set would actually look like?

Comment: Perhaps with more interesting lift data than "everyone does 185" since that's likely to not show what you really want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT -- join student a total weight to the student table 
    A.studentId,
    A.first,
    A.last,
    C.totalWeight
FROM 
    Student A,  
    (
         SELECT  -- for each studet add the max weights 
             sum(B.maxWeight) as totalWeight, 
             B.studentID
         FROM (
             SELECT  -- for each (student,lift) select the max weight 
                 max(weight) as maxWeight, 
                 studentId, 
                 liftID
             FROM 
                 StudentLifts
             GROUP BY 
                 studentId,
                 liftID
         ) B
         GROUP BY 
            studentId
     ) C
WHERE 
    A.studentID = C.studentId 
    -- AND A.weight >= 170
    -- AND A.weight < 170
            -- pick one here to generate on of the two lists.
```

Comment: This outputs the top weight for each student in each lift, but it does not add the total of the three lifts for each student.

Comment: Updated to give you what you wanted.